# Jenkins - Install recommended plugins via Ansible or CLI

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Is there a way to install the Jenkins recommended plugins (shown when installing it via wizard) when using Ansible?

[image]

I even started creating the list in my Ansible YML, but it is pretty long and the names sometimes don't match with the repository list [here](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/)

```
- name: Install plugin
    community.general.jenkins_plugin:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      url_username: "{{ jenkins_admin_username }}"
      url_password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
      url: http://localhost:8080
      timeout: 90
    with_items:
      - git
      - maven
      - thinbackup
      - build-pipeline-plugin
      - trilead-api
      - ant
```

A solution via CLI would also work fine.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/install/platform-plugins.json) a list with the recommended plugins.

```
- name: Install plugin
        community.general.jenkins_plugin:
          name: "{{ item }}"
          url_username: "{{ jenkins_admin_username }}"
          url_password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
          url: http://localhost:8080
          timeout: "{{ jenkins_plugins_timeout }}"
          state: latest
        with_items:  
          - ace-editor
          - ant
          - antisamy-markup-formatter
          - apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api
          - bootstrap4-api
          - bootstrap5-api
          - bouncycastle-api
          - branch-api
          - build-timeout
          - caffeine-api
          - checks-api
          - cloudbees-folder
          - command-launcher
          - credentials
          - credentials-binding
          - display-url-api
          - durable-task
          - echarts-api
          - email-ext
          - font-awesome-api
          - git
          - git-client
          - git-server
          - github
          - github-api
          - github-branch-source
          - gradle
          - handlebars
          - jackson2-api
          - jaxb
          - jdk-tool
          - jjwt-api
          - jquery3-api
          - jsch
          - junit
          - ldap
          - lockable-resources
          - mailer
          - matrix-auth
          - matrix-project
          - momentjs
          - okhttp-api
          - pam-auth
          - pipeline-build-step
          - pipeline-github-lib
          - pipeline-graph-analysis
          - pipeline-input-step
          - pipeline-milestone-step
          - pipeline-model-api
          - pipeline-model-definition
          - pipeline-model-extensions
          - pipeline-rest-api
          - pipeline-stage-step
          - pipeline-stage-tags-metadata
          - pipeline-stage-view
          - plain-credentials
          - plugin-util-api
          - popper-api
          - popper2-api
          - resource-disposer
          - scm-api
          - script-security
          - snakeyaml-api
          - ssh-credentials
          - ssh-slaves
          - sshd
          - structs
          - timestamper
          - token-macro
          - trilead-api
          - workflow-aggregator
          - workflow-api
          - workflow-basic-steps
          - workflow-cps
          - workflow-cps-global-lib
          - workflow-durable-task-step
          - workflow-job
          - workflow-multibranch
          - workflow-scm-step
          - workflow-step-api
          - workflow-support
          - ws-cleanup
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak to the Ansible part as I don't use it, though it does appear there is Ansible module to help you: [community.general.jenkins_plugin – Add or remove Jenkins plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/jenkins_plugin_module.html)

The master list of [recommended plugins is found in GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/install/platform-plugins.json); that's what the UI is built from.

The recommended CLI tool to install the plugins is the [Plugin Installation Manager Tool for Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/install/platform-plugins.json).

CLI tool can retrieve the latest compatible to the Jenkins version you have or specific versions.

I don't know if the Ansible module handles dependent plugins, but the CLI and the UI does.